# How can I use a mask in values came from database?

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm getting some data from my database and wanted to format it inside my view.
My code is simple, with a table bringing the data from database, but i want to show my phone with a mask: (12) 94832-3823.
Tried all sort os things, but no success, can anyone give me a hint?

My table code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="example10" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>{{ __('messages.serial no')}}</th>
         <th>{{ __('messages.Delivery_Boy')}}</th>
         <th>{{ __('messages.Delivery_Boy_Image')}}</th>
         <th>{{ __('messages.Delivery_Boy_Phone')}}</th>
         <th>{{ __('messages.Status')}}</th>
         <th>{{ __('messages.action')}}</th>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
   <tbody>
      @if(count($delivery_boy)>0)
      @php $i=1; @endphp
      @foreach($delivery_boy as $delivery_boys)
      <tr>
         <td>{{$i}}</td>
         <td>{{$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_name}}</td>
         <td align="center"><img src="{{url($delivery_boys->delivery_boy_image)}}" style="width: 21px;"></td>
         <td>{{$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_phone}}</td>
         <td>
            @if($delivery_boys->is_confirmed==0)
            <a href="{{route('confirm.delivery.status',[$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_id,'1'])}}" class="btn btn-info" style="color: #fff;">Yes</a>
            <a href="{{route('confirm.delivery.status',[$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_id,'2'])}}" class="btn btn-danger" style="color: #fff;">No</a>
            @elseif($delivery_boys->is_confirmed == 1)
            <span style="color:green;">Aprovado</span>
            @else
            <span style="color:red;">Reprovado</span>
            @endif
         </td>
         <td>
            <a href="{{route('edit-delivery_boy',$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_id)}}" style="width: 28px; padding-left: 6px;" class="btn btn-info"  style="width: 10px;padding-left: 9px;" style="color: #fff;"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="width: 10px;"></i></a>
            <button type="button" style="width: 28px; padding-left: 6px;" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
         </td>
      </tr>
      @php $i++; @endphp
      @endforeach
      @else
      <tr>
         <td>No data found</td>
      </tr>
      @endif
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How's it displaying now:
[image]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to remove the php echo phone and replace with hard coded text. Like that `<td>xxx-xxx-xxx</td>`.

### UPDATE

You tagged your question with javascript. Javascript version:
Only important would be the regex pattern. `/(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d+)/`

**javascript example**

```js
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
  
  var match = cleaned.match(/(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d+)/);  
  if (match) {
    return '(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3];
  }
  return null;
}

p = "+5511920140349"

console.log( formatPhoneNumber(p) )
```

### Appendix

Change this line with the phone number from `<td>{{$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_phone}}</td>`  to `<td class="phonenumbers">{{$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_phone}}</td>`. Now, you have a seelctor and can fetch the lines and modified by js. like that:

```js
const nums = document.querySelectorAll('.phonenumber');
console.log(nums)

nums.forEach(td => {
  const p = td.innerHTML;
  td.innerHTML = formatPhoneNumber(p)  
})


function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {  
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');  
  var match = cleaned.match(/(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d+)/);  
  if (match) {
    return '+(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3];
  }
  return null;
}
```

```html
<table border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td class="phonenumber">123456789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td class="phonenumber">123456789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td class="phonenumber">123456789</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: but then, how would i call the phone from db?

Comment: @eitibiti How did you do it before?

Comment: @eitibiti Your screenshot does not show that you can click on the telephone number. i do not know your goal. Your question confuses me. Why do you want to mask your number and then load it from the database? 

Comment: The phone is loaded from database, then i show it in the screenshot table.

Comment: I want the user to see the phone with a mask

Comment: the phone number isn't clickable, i just wanna show it with a mask

Comment: :-) yes now i understood. !!! i will updated my question soon. but regex would the soultion...

Comment: @eitibiti All numbers are equal long?

Comment: @eitibitiI updated my answer. take a look, please!

Comment: yes, all numbers are equal long, all cellphones

Comment: your answer was really helpful! i wanted a hint of how i could possibily implement this on my project, as soon as my data is coming from db

Comment: sorry for the dumb questions, i'm new to programming.

Comment: no problem. i updated my question. next time you have to find your own solution ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot bro! i understood the concept you used, contributed a lot to my learning process!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do with a simple regex replace, is replacing all the digits into a `X`.

So on the place where you want to show the 'masked' phone number you can place this:

```
preg_replace('/\d/', 'X', '+5511920140349');
```

Comment: bro, i want to format the existing phone into that mas, not showing only X's.

Comment: @eitibiti You've to change the third parameter to the phone variable.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Currently you show your phone number something like: `{{$user->phone_number}}` in a table (You didn't show us the code for the table where you show the phone number), instead of that you've to use `preg_replace('/\d/', 'X', $user->phone_number');`

Comment: sorry, wrong view! edited.

Comment: So in your current view you've to replace `{{$delivery_boys->delivery_boy_phone}}` with `{{preg_replace('/\d/', 'X', $delivery_boys->delivery_boy_phone)}}`